# Is there a way to know what the concentrations of various minerals and ions in the water of a human usable hot spring are?

Tags: water, mineralogy, open-data

I have heard that there are hot springs in Greece which contain high amounts of ions and minerals (namely Lithium) that some people believe has beneficial impact on mental health.

I can't verify/know the validity of those claims but I am curious if anyone knows the measurements of the actual grams of mineral/gallon amounts of various minerals that are in these human usable hot springs?

Answers to this question are any hot spring of your choice that has a link claiming to have health benefits and the actual scientifically measured ratios of its (grams of mineral)/gallon or liter of water.

Comment: have you tried google, many hot springs post this kind of stuff, its not that difficult to measure. I found dozens of papers about individual springs right away.  Japan even has laws regulating what can be called a hotspring based on it. it, that might be the closest to what you want. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Various-components-in-onsen-water-and-their-regulated-quantities-Source-Hot-Spring-Law_tbl2_230644923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is yes, absolutely, even if you buy some bottle of water you will find that the list of minerals dissolved in it is analyzed and written on the label.

The specific question in the text, about lithium and mental health, this is a mix-up of two different concept:

- there is lithium dissolved in hot geothermal water;
- lithium is the base ingredient of drugs used to treat bipolar disorders;

Whether this second question is true, it would be better to ask to the medical practitioners, if bathing in lithium rich water can improve mental health ...